# BeautifulSoup parsing the page without the authenticated session

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from multiple pages using scrapy and selenium
I successfully logged in using selenium driver but when my spider start scraping he doesn't use the logged in session from selenium and only scrape data available to any user ( non authenticated users )

```
class Brother(Spider):
name = "spiderbrother"
allowed_domain = ["mywebsite"]
start_urls = ['https://mywebsite../']
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'Equipe.pipelines.Brother': 500
    },
    'COOKIES_ENABLED': True
}

def parse(self, response):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://mywebsite../login")
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("passwd")
    username.send_keys("myEmail")
    password.send_keys("MyPWD")
    driver.find_element_by_name("SubmitLogin").click()
    categories = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="leo-top-menu"]/ul/li/a')
    for categorie in categories:
        page_url = categorie.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        next_page = response.urljoin(page_url)
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.types)

def types(self, response):

    sub_categories = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="subcategories"]/div/div/div/h5/a')
    for sub_categorie in sub_categories:
        page_url = sub_categorie.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        next_page = response.urljoin(page_url)
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.products)

def products(self, response):

    products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="product-image-container image"]/a')

    for product in products:
        url = product.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        page = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        item = TestItem()
        item["title"] = soup.find("h1").text
        item['image_url'] = soup.find("div", {"id": "image-block"}).img["src"]
        item['price'] = soup.find("span", {"id": "our_price_display"}).text
        try:
            item['availability'] = soup.find("span", {"id": "availability_value"}).text()
        except:
            item['availability'] = "Available"
        try:
            item['description'] = soup.find("div", {"itemprop": "description"}).text.strip()
        except:
            item['description'] = "no description found"
        yield item

    next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination_next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.products)
```

> I get every data except "Price" because it's only available while logged in
>
> Tried using the FormRequest to login instead of selenium still got the same problem .. i tried retrieving the data (only the price) before accessing the product's page and parsing it using BeautifulSoup and it worked .. seems that beautifulsoup was the problem here

I logged in with FormRequest

```
    def parse(self, response):
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                     formxpath="//*[@id='login_form']",
                                     formdata={'email': 'MyEmail', 'passwd': 'myPWD'},
                                     callback=self.after_login)

def after_login(self, response):
    categories = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="leo-top-menu"]/ul/li/a')
    for categorie in categories:
        page_url = categorie.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        next_page = response.urljoin(page_url)
        if next_page:
            yield Request(url=next_page, callback=self.types)
```

Comment: You have to figure out what kind of authentication the page is using. It can be a session cookie, so you could get the cookies from the driver instance and then add them to the scrapy request

Comment: @marke i actually saved the cookies in a variable "data = driver.get_cookies()" and called it in the Request but still had the same problem

Comment: tha page might use some other authentication method, like Token sent in the Authorization header. Other thing I can think of is that driver.get_cookies() returns a list of dicts, and scrapy's cookies takes a single dict of cookies and maybe this is where you are doing it wrong?

Comment: @marke i figured out the problem .. it was beautifulsoup parsing the html page without the session .. tried using FormRequest to login and extracting the price value before accessing the product's page and parsing it with beautifulsoup and i acutally got the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that `requests.get()` was opening the URL without the logged in session so i tried accessing it with `Request` and calling back a new method `parse_item()` so that Beatifulsoup parses from the response and it worked.

> The Updated Code

```
def products(self, response):
    products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="product-image-container image"]/a')
    for product in products:
        url = product.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        page = response.urljoin(url)
        yield Request(url=page, callback=self.parse_item)
    next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination_next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
    next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
    if next_page:
        yield Request(url=next_page, callback=self.products)

def parse_item(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    item = TestItem()
    item["title"] = soup.find("h1").text
    item['image_url'] = soup.find("div", {"id": "image-block"}).img["src"]
    item['price'] = soup.find("span", {"id": "our_price_display"}).text
    try:
        item['availability'] = soup.find("span", {"id": "availability_value"}).text()
    except:
        item['availability'] = "Available"
    try:
        item['description'] = soup.find("div", {"itemprop": "description"}).text.strip().replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
    except:
        print("no description found")
    yield item
```